# Parsing youtube from one category

Tags: node.js, youtube, phantomjs

I have a task to parse links and titles from YouTube videos from one category (e.g. music).

I know that there's a huge amount of videos so that's my question. How to do it using for example `nodeJS`?

I have only one idea simply to use `phantomJS` and scroll scroll scroll down page to get as many videos as I can, but this solution is dumb.

Are there any other solutions, using YouTube API for example or other tools and methods?

Comment: You  dont have links list? You want youtube api to provide all the music video links?

Comment: @AsifSaeed yes, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&key=Your Key Here

try using this. First find out which category video id you need